# Pin Map in Metabase not Showing pins

Tags: sql, metabase

I am trying to make Pin Map visualization based by Longitude and Latitude in Metabase, I use custom query to do so that run with this:

```
SELECT
    transaction_loc_latitude,
    transaction_loc_longitude,
    CAST(transaction_loc_latitude AS DECIMAL(17, 15)) AS latitude,
    CAST(transaction_loc_longitude AS DECIMAL(56, 15)) AS longitude
FROM
    mrg_merchant_transaction_2020_10
WHERE
    transaction_loc_longitude IS NOT NULL
    AND transaction_loc_latitude IS NOT NULL
    AND transaction_loc_longitude NOT IN ('0', '0.0', '0.00000000', '00')
    AND transaction_loc_latitude NOT IN ('0', '0.0', '0.00000000')
```

And here is query results with the screenshot:

[image]

After this, I am sure that the longitude and latitude is already decimal, and then I set it in the corresponding fields

[image]

**But the map didn't show any pins:**

[image]

How to make the pin appear? am I still miss something? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug if your request return more than 999 rows :

[Pin Maps with more than 1000 results (LeafletTilePinMap) not working with native queries](https://github.com/metabase/metabase/issues/7560)